# Animated GIF favicon for Firefox and static ICO for fallback

Tags: html, favicon

What would be the correct way of having an animated GIF icon for Firefox and a fallback ICO file for other browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<link href="/favicon.gif" rel="icon" type="image/gif" />
```

Must be specified in this order.